# Max of list with ascending then descending integers with duplicates

Tags: algorithm, search, max, binary-search

> You are given an array which increases at first and then starts
>   decreasing but with duplicates. For example: 2 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 3 3 3
>   3 2 2 1 . Find the maximum element of these array.

Is there a better way to solve this apart from a linear search? We could do a binary search with complexity of O(n), but it only works for a list that does not have duplicates side by side.